# Getting input from the keypad to show at a label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

My code is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)loopBtn:(id)sender {
    txtLoopBtn1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    [txtLoopBtn1 becomeFirstResponder];    
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

My `loopBtn` is calling the keypad from `txtLoopBtn1` as the responder like someone who taught me to add this code inside my `- (IBAction)loopBtn:(id)sender` using this code :

```
   txtLoopBtn1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
   [txtLoopBtn1 becomeFirstResponder];    
   [sender resignFirstResponder];
```

After i push loopBtn then the keypad showed. I added a number, but it didn't show at the `labelLoop`.

I already wrote down the code for showing my code but it failed and then I deleted it all. Now my `loopBtn` code is just like the sample above.

i just want to get input from numpad and then show at labelLoop but i don't know how to implement it. i'm sorry for my english.

please don't be upset first if you don't understand my problem. i just don't know how to explain to you using my google translate english.

Comment: what are you trying ?? i'm not getting you ..
do you want to add a text on uilabel from textfield ?

Comment: if you can not explain your question in short please use chat room where you can chat and ask your questions...

Comment: i am sorry, my reputation is not enough to chat in chatroom. it's okay. i can wait. thank you for watching my post.

Comment: If you are newB then you can share your gmail id ..... i can help you in my free time :-)

Comment: Thx mr Vakul. i dont have gmail, i have yahoo id, that is piyo_land@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

I already solve my question. I put txtLoopButton place inside my view next to loopBtn (replace my labelLoop with txtLoopButton) without border and then i delete my labelLoop. Because someone who taught me, he said that i must put my textLoopBtn outside my view if i want using below code.

```
   txtLoopBtn1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    [txtLoopBtn1 becomeFirstResponder];
```

Confuse, how to explain with my limited english. maybe i got misunderstanding what he said. But thank you for watching my noob question.